# How to get the rotation angle in Google Tango

Tags: java, android, google-project-tango

I am developing an indoor location app with Google's Project Tango device, and I want the UI to display the device orientation with regard to the ADF map.

For this purpose I am accessing the Z axis rotation information from TangoPoseData, and try to convert the rotation data back to an angle in degrees.

The rotation information in TangoPoseData being defined as follows,
`z = RotationAxis.z * sin(RotationAngle / 2)`

my code looks like this:

`//Sine value of the angle`
`double tangoRotationZsin = pose.rotation[2];`

`//Convert the sine value into a angle in radians`
`double tangoRotationZRad = 2*Math.asin(tangoRotationZsin);`

`//Convert to an angle in degrees`
`double tangoRotationZDeg = tangoRotationZRad * 180/Math.PI;`

### Problem:

The angle value in degrees (tangoRotationZDeg) should range from -180 to 180, but even if I rotate the device by 360 degrees several times on the Z axis, the angle ranges only from -120 to 120 degrees (or sometimes between -110 to 110 degrees).

What am I missing?
I guess that the problem has something to do with the "RotationAxis.z" factor in TangoPoseData which I assume equal to 1 in my code, but not sure.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Have you deliberately ruled out the use of quaternions ?

Comment: I am not developing a 3D app, but a 2D map much like Google Maps where a dot indicates the user position. My goal is to rotate this dot around the Z axis to indicate the user orientation. This dot is an Android bitmap rotated by the Matrix.postRotate(float degrees) function, and unfortunately this function requires an angle in degrees, not a quaternion (I am developing a Android app in Java, not using Unity). So I have no choice but trying to compute the original angle back from Pose data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this -- [SO Post on extracting yaw from a quaternion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782658/extracting-yaw-from-a-quaternion)  - note that the TangoPoseData rotation is a quaternion value, not a set of Euler angles