# From Front, Left & Up Vector to read Pitch, Yaw & Rol

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I have a CSV file with:
FrontX
FrontY
FrontZ
LeftX
LegtY
LeftZ
UpX
UpY
UpZ

And I want to convert that to roll, yaw and pitch. But I do not know the formula for this

Comment: [Extracting Yaw from a Quaternion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782658/extracting-yaw-from-a-quaternion) might help.  Since you seem to have three elements you need, the same formula might work for roll and pitch as well

Comment: [finding pitch/roll/yaw from Quaternions](https://answers.unity.com/questions/416169/finding-pitchrollyaw-from-quaternions.html) might also help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to calculate 3D rotation on X and Y axis from a 4x4 matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56900173/is-there-a-way-to-calculate-3d-rotation-on-x-and-y-axis-from-a-4x4-matrix)

Comment: see the duplicate ... you just construct transform matrix from your 3 vectors and pas it to the transformation (configured to your desired rotation order)...